# React component variable state don't keep last updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm using an event based library (powerbi-client-react)

First I should get the component from `getEmbeddedComponent` and set it in `report` variable
then use `report.getFilters()` ( promise based method )  to get some values.

I tried to get the values inside `getEmbeddedComponent`

```
getEmbeddedComponent={function (embeddedReport) {
  console.log("enter here", embeddedReport) // well entering here
  embeddedReport.getPages().then(function (filters) {
    console.log("get filters", filters);
  }).catch(function (errors) {
    console.log("error", errors);
  });
}}
```

But I get never inside the callback.

So I tried using `useState()` and trigger the `getFilters` inside `eventHandlers` but the values is always `{ test: "init" }`( the initial values

```
function App(props) {
  const [embedToken, setEmbedToken] = useState(props.token);
  const [report, setReport] = useState({ test: "init" });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.token === undefined) {
      props.requestToken();
    }
    setEmbedToken(props.token);
  }, [props.token]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QueuesFilter />
      <PowerBIEmbed
        embedConfig={{
          type: "report", // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
          id: props.reportInfos?.id,
          embedUrl: props.reportInfos?.embedUrl,
          accessToken: props.token,
          tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
          permissions: models.Permissions.All,
          settings: {
            panes: {
              filters: {
                expanded: true,
                visible: false,
              },
            },
            background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
          },
        }}
        eventHandlers={
          new Map([
            [
              "loaded",
              function (event) {
                console.log("Reporttest loaded", report);
              },
            ],
            [
              "rendered",
              function () {
                console.log("Reporttest rendered", report);
              },
            ],
            [
              "visualRendered",
              function () {
                console.log("Reporttest visualRendered", report);
              },
            ],
            [
              "error",
              function (event) {
                console.log(event.detail);
              },
            ],
          ])
        }
        cssClassName={"report-style-class"}
        getEmbeddedComponent={function (embeddedReport) {
          console.log("Reporttest getEmbeddedComponent", report);
          setReport(embeddedReport);
        }}
      />
      {/* <div className="report-style-class" ></div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I reloaded several time the app and get always the console logs in the same order
[image]

Comment: You are not able to get the latest value of report in the loaded event handler. Is this the exact issue?

Answer (score 2):

I see, you want to access the updated report object inside your event handlers.
The recommended way is to accept the updated report as the **second parameter** of event handler
Refer [Docs > Usage > Set event handlers](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react#usage)

```js
eventHandlers={
  new Map([
    [
      "loaded",
      function (event, report) {
        // 2nd param is the updated report object
        console.log("Reporttest loaded", report);
      },
    ],
    [
      "rendered",
      function (event, report) {
        console.log("Reporttest rendered", report);
      },
    ],
  ]
}
```

You are getting the old value of report state because, when the props are updated, the event handler map is updated in the PowerBIEmbed component only if the event/event handler is changed from previous props.
Therefore, the old event handler was invoked which referred to the old state of report variable due to [Closures in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)